# What is the purpose of the RG10MEG Resistor in this circuit?

Tags: resistors

What is the purpose of the RG10MEG Resistor in this circuit? Why is it there, I can't see any difference in the simulation when it's missing. PS: U_IN = 3V DC + 1.5V sinusoidal at 1kHz

[image: circuit]

Comment: Do you see a difference if you run it at the lower limits of human hearing frequency range? Try it at 20 Hz with and without RG.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzZFA0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Without the 1 MΩ RG resistor the bias circuit becomes a high-pass filter with a cut-off frequency of 10.3 Hz.*

The effective impedance at the junction of R1 - R2 is R1 || R2 = 19k || 11k = 7 kΩ.

Adding the 10 MΩ resistor drops the high-pass cut-off to 7 mHz.

Answer (score 0):

Since the gate of the MOSFET does not draw any DC current, the resistor has no effect on the operating point (i. e. the gate DC voltage). However, it increases the input impedance from RG1 || RG2 = 6.97 kOhm to well above 10 MOhm. In your simulation, this has no effect since the internal resistance of the source is zero and the cut-off frequency of the high-pass filter formed by C and the input impedance is low enough to let the 1 kHz signal pass, no matter whether RG is there or not.